# FactoryGirl not aware of new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Hi I am using FactoryGirl 4.9.0 w/ Rails 4.2.11. I added a boolean column to a model called `Query` like so:

```
class AddSetLatestResultToQueries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :queries, :latest_result_s3_url_flag, :boolean, null: false, default: false
  end
end
```

This flag works fine and the app itself works fine but when it comes to rspec, FactoryGirl seems to be having trouble acknowledging this new column.

I tried to add it to the factory model like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :query do
    latest_result_s3_url_flag false
    title 'some title'
    latest_body 'SELECT TIMEOFDAY();'

 ... etc ...

end
```

But when I run `rpsec spec`, I see this error:

```
      NoMethodError:
        undefined method `latest_result_s3_url_flag=' for #<Query:0x00007ff6f9108428>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you checked to make sure your test database was synced with your migration, however you are keeping your test db in sync?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run this:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Comment: face meets palm

Comment: Ouch.  I have two local db's.  While I kept checking one for correctness, the other was out of sync.  Thanks!

Comment: This could have saved me my precious 48 hours and some  brain pain. Could someone explain to a Ror newbie like me why this is needed?

Comment: ror keeps different DBs for different envs. test/development/production. when you develop you do it for dev env, when you deploy you do it for production. When for tests? Before you run tests. Check this doc https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#pending-migration-checks